# jQuery - Open all links in id in new window

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me of a way to open all links within an id in a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the head:

```
$(function () {
    $('#selector').attr('target', '_blank');
})
```

Comment: LOL... @Gausie That most likely wasn't funny but I just laughed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
$('#myId a').click(function() {
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works well! But please take note of the missing { after function().

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a single function that will open all the hyperlinks within an ID in new windows? That's what I thought. :P

```
$("#some_id a").each(function (i) {
    window.open(this.href);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myId').click(function(){
    this.target = "_blank";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id a').click(function() {
    this.target = "_blank";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say "all links" ,that i understand that **any** of specific link (e.g. may be more than one on the page) should guide to blank page.

For this case, you may do all needed links,that guide to blank page ,with specific id and dynamically generated postfix, e.g.:

link_1,
link_2
etc.

so the script will look like:

```
var linkId = "[id*=" + "link_]";
$(linkId).attr('target', '_blank');
```

here is regexp used.